# Count group by using mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, aggregate-functions

I'm trying to make some kind of "top" for some game stadistics

Table it's like this

```
mapname     authid  country     name    time    date    weapon  server
```

I've got this query, i think it's fine (lowest time per map it's shown)

```
SELECT name, min( time ) AS time
FROM kz_pro15
GROUP BY mapname ASC
```

and i'm getting results as

```
name    time
Santaaa     907.75
Zimmek*     184.82
:d  34.35
waldoo  1.04
Epiphany    8.54
Lovvon  185.51
Epiphany    64.53
menqz   73.67
waldoo  93.97
KoLkkE  207.83
q[o__o]p    78.35
Ulysses gc     T! CS    154.01
sasuke FTW  151.17
sasuke FTW  41.62
Santaaa     80.38
Santaaa     196.95
JonyBu  135.56
tiBU    93.12
Santaaa     122.04
Santaaa     36.08
EzzeqL  149.14
Zeqqe   106.75
bondiO^     110.68
INJUNABLES  102.09
Sublime     72.15
Player  106.11
=(M4t1ttU)=     158.95
foo conscience  80.98
gabe    27.21
gabe    58.5
```

But now i'm trying to count that results, to get how many records does players listed before has

```
gabe      2
sublime   1
player   13
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless `name` depends on `mapname`, your query is not correct:

```
SELECT name, min( time ) AS time
FROM kz_pro15
GROUP BY mapname ASC
```

It will show the `MIN(time)` for every `mapname` but there is no guarantee that it will show the relevant `name` with the minimum time.

Use this instead (and notice the subquery):

```
SELECT k.name
     , COUNT(*) AS cnt
FROM kz_pro15 AS k
  JOIN
    ( SELECT mapname 
           , MIN(time) AS time
      FROM kz_pro15
      GROUP BY mapname
    ) AS g
    ON (g.mapname, g.time) = (k.mapname, k.time)
GROUP BY k.name
```

Comment: I was about to mention the same thing :)

Comment: @ypercube, how about if i want to display the best 15 times for a custom mapname... same issue, i've got

SELECT *, min(time)
   FROM kz_nub15
   WHERE mapname = '".$map."'
   GROUP BY name ASC
   ORDER BY time ASC
   LIMIT 15

But min(time) it's not the exact value

Comment: If you want the best 15 times for a specific mapname, you don't need the `GROUP BY name` nor the `MIN(time)`, do you?

Comment: Or you mean, for a specific mapname, show best 15 times for **every** name?

Comment: @ypercube exactly, the best 15 times for a mapname, but only showing the best time of a name

Comment: I think that deserves another question (add the `[greatest-n-per-group]` tag or search questions/answers with that tag to solve it yourself).

Comment: @ypercube Oh right, u can check it right here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10012054/get-best-records-of-each-name-using-mysql. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT name, count(*)
FROM (
 SELECT name, min( time ) AS time
 FROM kz_pro15
 GROUP BY mapname ASC 
) AS x
GROUP BY name
```

Answer (score 0):

SELECT 
    name, 
    min( time ) AS time,
    count(*) AS records
FROM kz_pro15
GROUP BY name ASC