# Get best records of each name using mysql

Tags: mysql, greatest-n-per-group

I'm trying to make some kind of "top" for some game stadistics

Table it's like this

```
mapname     authid  country     name    time    date    weapon  server
```

I've got this query, but it's not ok

```
SELECT *, min(time) FROM kz_nub15 WHERE mapname = '".$map."' GROUP BY name ASC ORDER BY time ASC LIMIT 15
```

I'm trying to get the best 15 times for a mapname, but only showing the best time of each name

Answer (score 0):

How about trying it this way:

```
SELECT *
FROM kz_nub15
WHERE mapname = '".$map."'
GROUP BY name
ORDER BY time ASC
LIMIT 15
```

Comment: The problem it's when grouping by name, the value that takes it's not the lowest

Comment: It should be the lowest value for that specific name, what are you expecting instead?

Comment: There are more than one record for name, ie

name1-20
name2-30
name1-25

And when grouping by, i'm not getting the lowest time for name1

Comment: Right, that's why in that case you'll get the record with the lowest time for each different name

Comment: Sorry @darkajax, but not, the group by doesn't get the lowest time associated

Answer (score 0):

This is because of min() , take out min() and try again.

Comment: It's the same i've told @darkajax. When grouping by, i'm not getting the lowest time